# Access AWS Cloudwatch event "Additional parameters" from lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an AWS Cloudwatch event that is runon  a cron schedule that triggers a Lambda and I want to specify "Additional parameters" in the rule definition and have these passed into the Lambda.

1. How do I configure the "Additional parameters" in the cloudwatch rule?
2. How do I access the rules "Additional parameters" in the Lambda
   function (its coded in c#)

Comment: When you define the target go to Configure input and use constant or input transformer.

Comment: Yes, that looks good. Do you know how to set the constant json when deploying from the commandline, dotnet lambda deploy-serverless, I've just gone through all the params (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/deploying-net-core-aws-lambda-functions-from-the-command-line/) and cant see how to send the json down.

Comment: May be this will help (see the last example): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/events/put-rule.html

Comment: Perfect, that is what I was failing to find. Thanks.